# Adding server logic to GAE Android backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I am developing an Android app and I want to add to it a Google App Engine backend.
It is the first time I do something like that, so I am following the Google tutorial, by which I can create entities and endpoints class to access them on the server.
My question is what is the best way to add some logic in my server backend?
What I would like to do is developing a little server app that does some work, not only answering my client app with the entities data.

A possible scenario can be: I have on my backend an entity called ELEMENT that has an associated image. For example, I might use an url attribute in the entity to associate the element with its image. When my android app makes a call through the ELEMENT endpoint to retrieve all the element info, I would like to run some code on my server that download the image using the url and then send it back along with the other element data.

I hope I was clear and I know it might appear a straightforward question, but I would like to understand what is the best approach to take and if maybe there are already standardized and easy-to-use solutions for something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply write some code in your endpoint classes that run on App Engine!

Read the "Phase 2: Building the Business Logic" of [this article](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/).

edit -

If you want to do a batch job you can use "[Scheduled Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron)"

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, this code would run just any time I make a call, right? What if I would like to download these images independently by client requests and store them somewhere?

Comment: Right, it's run in every call. If you want to do a batch job use cronjobs, search for App Engine task queue :) I've edited the answer with a link to that.